# How to create cascading drop down in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have requirement where I have to create a cascading dropdown, means the value of the second dropdown will depends on the first one. The list are going to be hardcoded.

For e.g. The first dropdown of country and based on this value the second dropdown is of state corresponding to that country; I will have the list of state corresponding to each country.

Now I know how to apply constraint on the field using list but can that be extended to two level ??

I have also searched about datalist but I really don't want that as the list is going to be pan customer but datalist will make it customer specific and don't want customer to create the list themselves.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the alfresco version you are using, is AIKAU an option for you ?

Comment: I am using **Alfresco 5.0.d**. I have heard about AIKAU but I am completely new to Alfresco so will be hard for me to proceed with it.

Comment: I provided an anwser that details how should/could this be implemented in aikau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some useful info: https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/cascading-dropdown-alfresco-share-03102011

Used that as a basis for my own cascading selects. Builds on the same concept as described by Marco Altieri

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco does not have cascading dropdown lists out of the box.
Nevertheless, it will not be difficult to develop one.

Because your lists are hardcoded, there is a simple solution.
Generate the controls for the two dropdown lists. They can even be just an hidden field or an empty dropdown. If you are not familiar with the Alfresco form engine, it will be probably easier to use an hidden field like in the following example (snippet of the configuration in share-config-custom.xml):

```
<field id="dropdown1">
  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/hidden.ftl">
     <control-param name="contextProperty">dropdown1</control-param>
  </control>
</field>
<field id="dropdown2">
  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/hidden.ftl">
     <control-param name="contextProperty">dropdown2</control-param>
  </control>
</field>
```

In share-config-custom.xml, you can also add a new custom javascript and css:

```
<!-- Document Library client-side dependencies -->
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocLibCustom">
  <dependencies>
     <js src="/js/cascading-dropdown.js" />
     <css src="/css/cascading-dropdown.css" />
  </dependencies>
</config>
```

The custom javascript and css can, using YUI, find the two controls and generate the necessary dropdown and event listeners. When the dropdown is updated, an event listener will update the cascading dropdown and will also update the hidden fields. The value of the hidden fields will be posted when the form is closed.

A better solution can be to use the custom javascript only to define a javascript library. You can then use this javascript library in a custom free marker template to use instead of "/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/hidden.ftl"

You can find hidden.ftl in:

/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/hidden.ftl

Do a copy of this ftl in the extension path and modify it to use your custom javascript.

If the lists are not hardcoded, simply use a webscript to generate the list and call it from the browser using ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

As you are with alfresco community edition 5.0.d, you can/should be using [aikau](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/aikau-intro.html) for that sort of things, you can start learning and using aikau based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/master/tutorial/chapters/Contents.md) for standalone aikau clients or [this tutorial](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2013/02/21/simple-page-creation-in-share/) for new custom share pages.

Once you have your page setup (desc.xml, js and ftl), you should have something like this:

**custom-page.get.desc.xml**

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>Test page 1</shortname>
  <family>testing</family>
  <url>/custom-uri</url>
</webscript>
```

**custom-page.get.ftl**

```
<@processJsonModel group="share"/>
```

and  **custom-page.get.js**

```
model.jsonModel = {
    services : [ "alfresco/services/NavigationService",
            "alfresco/services/LogoutService",
            // Add more services here !!!
            ],
    widgets : [ 
        // Add more widgets here
    ]
};
```

You need now to add two selects to your widgets array:

```
{
    name : "alfresco/forms/Form",
    config : {
        scopeFormControls : false, // to avoid complex handling of
        // pubSubScope

        widgets : [ {
            name : "alfresco/forms/controls/Select",
            config : {
                fieldId : "LEVEL_1",
                label : "Level 1",
                description : "Select an item from the list",
                name : "level_1",
                value : "1",
                requirementConfig : {
                    initialValue : true
                },
                optionsConfig : {
                    fixed : [ {
                        label : "Item 1",
                        value : "1"
                    }, {
                        label : "Item 2",
                        value : "2"
                    }, {
                        label : "Item 3",
                        value : "3"
                    } ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            name : "alfresco/forms/controls/Select",
            id : "LEVEL_2",
            config : {
                fieldId : "LEVEL_2",
                label : "Level 2",
                description : "Select an item from the list",
                name : "level_2",
                requirementConfig : {
                    initialValue : true
                },
                optionsConfig : {
                    fixed : [ {
                        label : "Item 1.1",
                        value : "1"
                    }, {
                        label : "Item 1.2",
                        value : "2"
                    }, {
                        label : "Item 1.3",
                        value : "3"
                    } ]
                }
            }
        } ]
    }
}
```

The next step would be to detect the change event in your first select then refresh the list of the second select with new items. In order to do so, you need either to define a new service or extend the select widget for your second select. I will go with option number 1:
**CustomServiceForNestedSelects.js**

```
define(
        [ "dojo/_base/declare", "alfresco/core/Core", "dojo/_base/lang",
                "alfresco/core/CoreXhr", "service/constants/Default" ],
        function(declare, Core, lang, CoreXhr, AlfConstants) {

            return declare(
                    [ Core, CoreXhr ],
                    {
                        pubSubScope : "",
                        levelOneFieldId : "LEVEL_1",
                        levelTwoFieldId : "LEVEL_2",
                        levelTwoItems : [ [ {
                            label : "Item 1.1",
                            value : "1"
                        }, {
                            label : "Item 1.2",
                            value : "2"
                        }, {
                            label : "Item 1.3",
                            value : "3"
                        } ], [ {
                            label : "Item 2.1",
                            value : "1"
                        }, {
                            label : "Item 2.2",
                            value : "2"
                        }, {
                            label : "Item 2.3",
                            value : "3"
                        } ], [ {
                            label : "Item 3.1",
                            value : "1"
                        }, {
                            label : "Item 3.2",
                            value : "2"
                        }, {
                            label : "Item 3.3",
                            value : "3"
                        } ] ],
                        constructor : function yreg_CustomServiceForNestedSelects__constructor(
                                args) {
                            lang.mixin(this, args);

                            this.alfSubscribe(this.pubSubScope
                                    + "_valueChangeOf_" + this.levelOneFieldId,
                                    lang.hitch(this, this.levelOneChanged));
                        },
                        levelOneChanged : function yreg_CustomServiceForNestedSelects__levelOneChanged(
                                payload) {
                            var value = payload.value;
                            var levelTwo = dijit.byId(this.levelTwoFieldId);
                            if (levelTwo)
                                levelTwo
                                        .setOptions(this.levelTwoItems[value - 1]);
                        },

                    });
        });
```

And now, all that is left is to include your service in your page model

```
"<custom-package>/CustomServiceForNestedSelects"
```

**Note:**

- You will need to register a custom package and place your service there, in order to learn how to do so, check [this tutorial](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/master/tutorial/chapters/Tutorial2.md#step-1-adding-a-new-package).
- To test your page's content check http://127.0.0.1:8090/aikau-sample/page/na/ws/custom-uri in case you are trying this code in a stand alone aikau app, or http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/dp/ws/custom-uri, http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/hdp/ws/custom-uri for share custom pages

Answer (score 1):

Aikau does actually provide cascading menus out-of-the-box, see the alfresco/menus/AlfCascadingMenu widget. There are examples of its use already present within Alfresco (for example the favourites list from under the sites menu in the main header in Share). If you already know the cascading contents then this can all be defined in your page WebScript. However, if you need to dynamically change the content of the cascaded menu then you should look at the implementation of alfresco/header/AlfSitesMenu or alfresco/documentlibrary/AlfCreateTemplateContentMenu (you can find the source in the [Aikau GitHub project](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau)).